# Docker - which images need to be transferred when moving to a new host in multi-layer app?

Tags: linux, image, ubuntu, docker

I have 3 parts in docker: 
1) MySql DB
2) Frontend UI
3) Backend

After building all with docker-compose.yml (via `docker-compose up`) - it created 6 images (some of them are base images - created by Docker during a process):

```
backend             latest              8e5a37121e7e        35 minutes ago      1.42GB
web                 latest              d882be1dccca        6 hours ago         533MB
mysql               latest              f2f8fece1645        6 hours ago         407MB
ubuntu              16.04               f975c5035748        3 weeks ago         112MB
ubuntu              16.10               7d3f705d307c        8 months ago        107MB
mysql               5.7.17              9546ca122d3a        12 months ago       407MB
```

Now I want to transfer whole App to another host and load images into new docker.

Which images I need to transfer? All 6 or only 3?
Any specific order of loading images in a new host?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to move 3 which is showing as latest.